# What is the domain for which this integral transform is defined?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, transformation, mobius-function

Let $s=\sigma+it$ the complex variable where thus $i^2 =-1$, and $\sigma$ and $t$ are real numbers. Let $\mu(k)$ the **Möbius function.** It is possible determine the set of functions such that

$$M \left\{ f(t) \right\} =i\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)\log k}{k^{it}}\int_0^\infty\frac{f(t)}{k^s}dt$$
is defined?

I don't know if the rigth question is the previous since I believe that I need to provide also an abscissa $\sigma$. I thought of the previous *transform* when I've tried reproduce the shape of the Dirichlet series $$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{k^s},$$ where is required that $\Re s=\sigma>1$. Then I can reproduce it so for $\sigma>1$ 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty i\frac{\log k}{k^{it}}\int_0^\infty e^{-it\log k}\frac{\mu(k)}{k^{\sigma}}1dt=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)},$$
that is: for  $\sigma>1$ then $M \left\{ 1 \right\}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$. I believe (I did computations for $M \left\{ 1 \right\}$, and also for $M \left\{ e^{-x} \right\}$) that my construction, when $g(s)=M \left\{ f(t) \right\}$ is defined, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Re g(s)=(\Im g(s))'$, and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Im g(s)=-(\Re g(s))'$, where with the derivative $'$ we denote the derivative of arithmetic functions, that is multiply by $\log k$.

Then my question is

> **Question.** It is possible determine the set of functions such that 
>   $$M \left\{ f(t) \right\} =i\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)\log k}{k^{it}}\int_0^\infty\frac{f(t)}{k^s}dt$$
>   is defined? It is neccesary require more conditions for which my problem is well-possed?

My computations were that it is obvious that $M \left\{ \cdot \right\} $ is linear and when the following is defined, one has
$$ \left|M \left\{ f(t) \right\} \right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\log k}{k^\sigma} \int_0^\infty  \left| f(t) \right|dt. $$

Seem that one needs conditions for the definition of such *transform* since $\int_0^\infty  \left| f(t) \right|dt$ could be not defined.

Thus I don't know if my previous questions makes sense, and I would like to know if it is possible define the previous *transform*, as I've said I've computed also the transform of a negative expoenential. **Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral is with respect to $t
 $ so you can't take $k^{-it}
 $ outside the integral. We can observe that, since $s=\sigma+it
 $, $$\left|i\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\mu\left(k\right)\log\left(k\right)}{k^{\sigma}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f\left(t\right)}{k^{2it}}dt\right|\leq\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\log\left(k\right)}{k^{\sigma}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|dt
 $$ so we have the convergence if $\sigma>1
 $ and $f\in L^{1}\left(\left(0,\infty\right)\right)
 $.

Comment: I've take remarks from your useful claims, but my transformation was defined with $k^{-it}$ outside the integral, notice that if now I am not wrong in this, also there is other factor $k^{-it}$ inside of the integral, as was defined it. Very thanks much. Of course I am not saying that there was a mistake, only that I don't undestand your first claim about the factor.

Comment: @user243301 Sorry but it is not true. The integral is with respect to $t$, so you can not take $k^{-it}$ outside the integral. If you want some power of $k$ you have to change letter.

Comment: I understand your words, very thanks one more time.